# How many ways to make change using specific amounts.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I am trying to figure out a recurrence relation or any kind of formula really that returns the number of ways to calculate a specific amount $n$ using only $3, 4, 5$.
So for $8$ you can do either $4+4$ or $5+3$. I know it's related to Partitioning and the coin change problem, but I can't figure out how to do it for these or any specific amounts.

Comment: Is $3+5$ counted as the same as $5+3$?

Comment: Order does not matter, so yes those are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Your question is about **restricted partitions** and is best analyzed using **generating functions**.

Specifically, if $T$ is a finite set of positive integers and $a_n$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of integers from $T$ (repetitions allowed), one considers the power series
$$
g_T(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \,. 
$$
In your case, $T = \{3,4,5\}$ and therefore
$$
g_T(x) = x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + 2x^8 + 2x^9 + 2x^{10} + 2x^{11} + 3x^{12} + \dots 
$$
It turns out that
$$
g_T(x) = \prod_{k \in T} \frac{1}{1-x^k}
$$
which allows the rapid computation of all $a_n$. For example $a_{200} = 354$, so there are exactly 354 ways to write 200 as sum of multiples of 3, 4, 5, see [this Wolfram Alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B1%2F((1-x%5E3)*(1-x%5E4)*(1-x%5E5)),%7Bx,0,200%7D%5D) . For details, looks at the Wikipedia article on [generating functions and partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense(I think haha). However, is there any way to phrase this as a recurrence relation? Or is this the only way to solve the question?